# Python function within function

Tags: python

I am reading LPTHW book and can't make this work

```
def raz(i):
    word = i.split(' ')
    return word

def prva(string):
    word = raz(string) # should use raz function like in book example but it gives error instead
    prva = word.pop(0)
    return prva
```

I am trying to get first word with 'prva' function, to break my sentence I am trying to use 'raz' function... But it returns error:

"TypeError: 'list' object is not callable."

Probably doesn't matter but below I am using function like this:

```
file = 'test.txt'
normal = odpri(file)
prva = prva(normal)
print "%s" % prva
```

Cheers

Comment: Is that the complete code? You somewhere have a line like - `raz = <some list>` , which is overwriting the `raz()` function you created.

Comment: The code as posted works just fine. What is the *full traceback* for the exception? Did you have any other code that might have replaced `raz` with a list somewhere? Function names live in the same namespace as variables.

Comment: Nema Ga, please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and follow the advice there. when you are finished, copy-paste the resulting program into your question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that was it, thanks. There was variable with the same name ... feelig dumb :P